# Grails Static Mapping argument type mismatch when saving

Tags: grails, types, save, arguments, mismatch

I can make a simple grails app in 2.4.4, but as soon as I add in static mapping that changes the name of the primary key it refuses to save. Here is the domain class I use.

```
    class Liaison {
        String first;
        String last;
    static constraints = {}

    static mapping = {
       id column:'liaisonId', type: 'integer'
    }
    }
```

here is the generated controller

```
  import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
  import grails.transaction.Transactional

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  class LiaisonController {

  static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

   def index(Integer max) {
     params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond Liaison.list(params), model:[liaisonInstanceCount: Liaison.count()]
}

def show(Liaison liaisonInstance) {
    respond liaisonInstance
}

def create() {
    respond new Liaison(params)
}

@Transactional
def save(Liaison liaisonInstance) {
    if (liaisonInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (liaisonInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond liaisonInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    liaisonInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'liaison.label', default: 'Liaison'), liaisonInstance.id])
            redirect liaisonInstance
        }
        '*' { respond liaisonInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}

def edit(Liaison liaisonInstance) {
    respond liaisonInstance
}

@Transactional
def update(Liaison liaisonInstance) {
    if (liaisonInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (liaisonInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond liaisonInstance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    liaisonInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'Liaison.label', default: 'Liaison'), liaisonInstance.id])
            redirect liaisonInstance
        }
        '*'{ respond liaisonInstance, [status: OK] }
    }
}

@Transactional
def delete(Liaison liaisonInstance) {

    if (liaisonInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    liaisonInstance.delete flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'Liaison.label', default: 'Liaison'), liaisonInstance.id])
            redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
    }
}

protected void notFound() {
    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'liaison.label', default: 'Liaison'), params.id])
            redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
    }
}
}
```

I get an error at liaisonInstance.save flush:true in the def save(), but I don't understand why. If I look in my change log the table looks to be fine. Is it some sort of hidden hash map? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Omg I think I get it. I was over-thinking. The static mapping should be

```
static mapping = {
    id column: 'liaisonId'
}
```

instead of

```
static mapping = {
    id column: 'liaisonId', type: 'integer'
}
```

I think it has to do with the auto generated primary key is a bigInt. I think type is only for if you plan on using an id generator for primary key.